# dev container with conda env: test folder does not recognize src folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, environment, vscode-devcontainer

I have a conda env inside a dev container. I use VS code. I can build my dev container succesfully, install all dependencies for conda env and I can develop inside my source folder.

However, I can't debug or run tests. Vs code is always returning `Test discovery failed`. This is the error code from `pytest`:

```
ImportError while loading conftest '/workspaces/backend/tests/conftest.py'.
tests/conftest.py:12: in <module>
    from ent.models.control import USER
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ent'
```

I don't know why I get this error.

my project folder looks like:

```
src
    - ent
        - models
            - control

tests
    - conftest
```

Comment: I have __init__.py files in every folder

Comment: -What is the content of "USER"? Please try to add "_import sys sys.path.append("./")_" at the beginning of the file "conftest.py" and use "_from src.ent.models.control import USER_". About "testing" in VS Code, you could refer to it: [Python testing in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_pytest-configuration-settings).